# tf.keras.utils.get_file in Colab coverts csv to html format

Tags: html, csv, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

I am loading a csv file from GDrive. The csv file was downloaded from the internet. I am on MacOS and the size of the csv file on my Mac's terminal is the same, however, when I check the head of the files from the terminal i guess

> head /Users/chekadsarami/Downloads/P2_Training_Dataset.csv 
>   thread_id,comment_id,reply_to,text,author,timestamp,author_flair,author_score,delta
>   181jmd,181jmd,181jmd,"Here's what I would change about American gun
>   regulations. CMV. Stipulated: improving the way we regulate guns is
>   not the only way to reduce the frequency at which we're violently
>   killing eac

But on colab, it shows an html file

```
!head {train_file_path}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=300, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
  <meta name="description" content="Google Drive is a free way to keep your files backed up and easy to reach from any phone, tablet, or computer. Start with 15GB of Google storage – free.">
  <meta name="google-site-verification" content="LrdTUW9psUAMbh4Ia074-BPEVmcpBxF6Gwf0MSgQXZs">
  <title>Meet Google Drive – One place for all your files</title>
  <style>
```

what is going on? I check the file name and sizes are the same. Here is the link to the [colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/17xSR1sV0VCrQYO9DKXIMZZuvAEqDh0VD).

Any help would be appreciated.

CS

Answer (score 0):

`tf.keras.utils.get_file("auto-mpg.data", "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data", extract = True)`

Add `extract = True` if the file is zipped

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10436